# Golang Gorilla/session

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm trying to build a simple web application with a user login.

I found this function in another post here.

```
func initSession(r *http.Request) *sessions.Session {
    session, _ := store.Get(r, "mBoxStore")
    if session.IsNew {
        session.Options.Domain = "localhost"
        session.Options.MaxAge = 10
        session.Options.HttpOnly = false
        session.Options.Secure = false
        log.Println("Create New Session (cookie)")
    } else {
        log.Println("Use Old Session (old cookie)")
    }
    return session
}
```

The cookie expires after `10 seconds`, but when i reload the page after e.g. `1 Minute`
it use the old (expired) cookie.

In my browser (Firefox) i see the cookie with the right expire date.

I think it should create a new session  with a new cookie or it is wrong ?

any tips ?

Comment: You are better off setting your options per store upon application startup. Then just use `session.Get` in your handlers (and check for errors). The `sessions` docs cover it well: http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. The Problem is not the Code ...it works for me...i can save and read data from the the session...
But it ignores the expire Date from the cookie.
it uses always the "old" Cookie.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you're seeing `Use Old Session (old cookie)` is because the session options are **only** being set when the cookie is first created. Each time you access the cookie *before* it expires (`isNew == false`) `Options` are not being set, and the defaults are overriding those you set on creation of the session. The default `MaxAge` is [86400 * 30](https://github.com/gorilla/securecookie/blob/master/securecookie.go#L50) (one month).

You can verify this by:

1. Clearing all cookies for the site (i.e. localhost)
2. Bringing up a route in your browser
3. Checking the expiry date on the freshly created cookie - you'll see it's now + 10 seconds
4. Wait out that 10 seconds.
5. Refresh the page - your log should confirm it's a new cookie.
6. Now refresh the page before the cookie expires (i.e. within 10 seconds)
7. You'll see the expiry has an expiry of now + 1 month (the default).

This is why I suggest setting your session options once, on application startup. Only deviate if you are setting shorter cookie lifetimes for authentication security purposes, and in those cases use a different session name (i.e. `_csrf_token` with an expiry of 4 hours).

The code snippet you're using isn't really ideal either as it completely ignores any errors encountered when trying to retrieve a session. You might run into errors if your underlying session store is broken, and/or the user has cookies disabled.

Comment: Thanks for you help :)
Now i see the Problem.
i didnt see the expire "month" in the new cookie , i only look at the create time.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear (wasn't clear to me at first when the answer said *I suggest setting your session options once, on app startup*), the store has an `.Options`, just like the `session.Options`.  Therefore: `var sessionStore = sessions.NewCookieStore(...)` and then `sessionStore.Options = &sessions.Options{ MaxAge: ... }` and so on

Comment: Be aware: `NewCookieStore(...)` calls `sessionStore.MaxAge()` with the default value of `86400 * 30` (1 month). This function has a for loop that sets the max age of all the underlying cookies in the store from the point of view of the server.

Setting the struct field `.Options{MaxAge: ... }` as in the above comment will set the expiration date of future cookies sent to the browser, but that expiration date will **not** be reflected in the server's record of the cookies. To avoid a discrepancy between browser/server expiration dates use `sessionStore.MaxAge()` instead